# Google Play Game Services issues when debugging on android 2.36

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm just trying to get the google game services for android working on my phone but I am having a few issues. I'm very new to android development so I apologies if it is a wasteful or poorly explained question. thanks.

I am using the following two Libraries:
**google-play-services_lib

and

BaseGameUtils**

My code compiles ok with just one superficial warning (below). When I try run it on my android 2.36 (edit: I do not have access to any other testing devices) it will flash up on the screen for a moment and then ask to force close.

If I debug it I get the following screen:
The top line says "*The JAR of this class file belongs to container 'Android Private Libraries' whoch does not allow modifactions to source attachments on its entries*"
[image: debug screen]

The current warning is:
The import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult is never used BaseGameActivity.java   /BaseGameUtils/src/com/google/example/games/basegameutils

I had to set the build path for both Libraries and the main project to 4.2 so that BuildGameUtils would compile ok (not too sure if this alone should exclude my device from running it)

I am essentially just following the tutorial at: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Also, my logcat looks as follows:

```
08-14 02:23:41.569: W/ActivityThread(8641): Application com.example.gggg is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
08-14 02:23:41.579: I/System.out(8641): Sending WAIT chunk
08-14 02:23:41.779: I/System.out(8641): Debugger has connected
08-14 02:23:41.779: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:41.989: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:42.179: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:42.389: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:42.589: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:42.789: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:42.989: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:43.189: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:43.399: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:43.599: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:43.789: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:43.999: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:44.189: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:44.399: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:44.599: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:44.789: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:44.999: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:45.199: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:45.399: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:45.599: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:45.809: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:46.009: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:46.209: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:46.399: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:46.609: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:46.809: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:46.999: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:47.209: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:47.409: I/System.out(8641): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-14 02:23:47.609: I/System.out(8641): debugger has settled (1425)
08-14 02:23:47.749: W/dalvikvm(8641): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/bv$b;' failed
08-14 02:23:47.749: E/dalvikvm(8641): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.bv$b', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.bv.a
08-14 02:23:47.749: W/dalvikvm(8641): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 740 (Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/bv$b;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/bv;
08-14 02:23:47.799: W/dalvikvm(8641): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 25
08-14 02:23:48.289: W/dalvikvm(8641): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 3636: Landroid/os/RemoteException;.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your google services ID is also correctly set in your XML file.**

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="YOUR GOOGLE SERVICES ID"/>
```

The ID is obtained on Google Developer Console -> Game Services.



**Also make sure your package name is identical in both places:**
-Manifest XML file of your android application.

```
<manifest   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
```

-Google developer console -> game services side.

**Couple of more things you should know:**
-The main google account used on your android device MUST be also listed in Google Developer Console -> Settings -> LICENSE TESTING (before you publish your APK). If the account is not listed, you will have no access to the services inside your application until the game is published.

Hope it helps,

Vladimir

Comment: I see same issue with same sw on same target. The advise above - however accurate and good - does not help, I have tried. This seem to be a lib/build path issue if anything.